# Do I have any trading cards drops left?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I remember I received a few trading cards for the game 'Space Run', but I sold them and I don't remember how many I received or how many there were available in the first place.

I found out that under 'Badges' in my profile on Steam I can see all the available badges to create for all the games I own. It also tells me per game how many trading cards there are left to earn by just playing it. However, 'Space Run' is not in the list, **probably because there are no badges available for it.**

**Where can I see how many card drops there are left for a game?** Because the 'Badges' section only seems to apply to games that have badges instead of games that have trading cards.

For what it's worth; my Steam level is 10.
NOTE: there are more games where the same applies, this is not specific to 'Space Run'.

Example games that have steam trading cards but do not appear in the Badges list:

- Game Corp Dx
- Space Run
- Lyne
- Middle Earth: Shadow Of Mordor
- Plantera

This applies to games both installed and not installed.

Screenshot to clarify (sorted on A-Z):
[image: So how many card drops are there left?]

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain? Is there something I can improve to this question?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. For starters, all games with badges have trading cards, because cards are how you get badges — so that part of the question is confusing. Do you know how to check badge progress (= how many cards you have for a game)? Do you still have Space Run on your account?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I still have Space Run on my account, another example is Game Corp Dx. I don't know how to describe it in a more clear way. 'Games with Trading Cards' != 'Games with Badges', however 'Games with Badges' == 'Games with Trading Cards', it is a subset of it. If you know a better way to describe it feel free to edit it in.

Comment: Ah, so you mean you're looking at the list of games *you* have badges for. Yeah, that's different than the set of games that have badges, as in the feature itself.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not sure I understand you correctly, I just navigated to Badges under my profile name. I have no badges for games, but it does display the available trading cards for the games that have badges available though. Maybe I should add a screenshot...

Comment: Did you complete a badge for the game at any point? Or did you sell all the cards you got? Also, make sure you've sorted teh badges "A-Z", just in case.

Comment: @DJPirtu, No I never completed a badge. I tried every sorting already and the games in the screenshot are sorted on A-Z. I sold all the cards.

Comment: Another clarification: are you asking if you've ever gotten at least one of each Space Run card, or are you asking if you have any card drops left?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The latter. "Are there any drops left?"

Comment: @Angzuril A-Z is the ordering. I add it to the question.

Comment: You could also just play the game a bit. If you don't get a card, there were no drops left.

Comment: @mbomb007 I understand that works, but I got ~250 games in my library. Not all of them have trading cards of course, but still, it would take a lot of my time to just try it out.

Comment: Yeah... maybe there's a way to get that info using the Steam API? http://steamcommunity.com/dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The badge list doesn't show all the games that you've ever received trading cards for. Basically, games will be hidden from that list if:

- you own none of the cards, and
- you have no card drops remaining, and
- you have no recent playtime, and
- you have not crafted the badge ever

You don't have to worry about remaining card drops being hidden from you. If you had any, the game would show up in the list.

You can manually check by going to [https://steamcommunity.com/my/gamecards/XXXX](https://steamcommunity.com/my/gamecards/275670), where XXXX is the game's app ID.

Comment: I don't get your first bullet point. You can clearly see in the screenshot that I own none cards for some games, I actually never installed these games yet. Could you elaborate your first point?

Comment: Now that I think of it, your first three bullet points are incorrect. I got games listed for which I received all cards, I got games listed for which I did not received any card your, and most games in my list have no play time at all. Sorry, but the first part of your answer just seems incorrect.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid **All** of these conditions have to be met for the game to be hidden, not just one.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't so clear, perhaps edit that in? Any idea how long ago 'recent playtime' is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure recent means the last 2 weeks

Comment: I just started Lyne and it appears again in the badge list, so that's confirmed. :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to find what you're looking for, and should work for any game on Steam that has cards, but this seems like a bug since Space Run appears to have a badge. Anyway:

If you click on one of those games on the "Badges" page, it takes you to a full list of available cards for that game. The web address for that page looks like this:

> steamcommunity.com/id/**yoursteamID**/gamecards/**72850**

That number is the unique game ID; in this case, 72850 is Skyrim's ID. You can get this ID from the game's Store page web address:

> store.steampowered.com/app/72850

The ID for Space Run is 275670. Replace the number above with that number and you'll see the game cards you have, as well as the number of drops you have left:

> steamcommunity.com/id/**yoursteamID**/gamecards/**275670**

Repeat for any game you can't see and want to check. I'd submit a support ticket to Steam as well, but I doubt you'll get very far with that...